# how read values from resource file in external .js files

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = '<%= Resources.booking.BookingApprovedNotification%>';
    alert(msg);
</script>
```

I have removed the above code from an aspx page to new javaScript file. Now I am trying to access the resource file but it is not accessible. Can any one help me?

Comment: do you understand that when fetching an asp page, the browser will not get `var msg = '<%= Resources.booking.BookingApprovedNotification%>';` rather, `var msg='whatever the value of Resources.booking.BookingApprovedNotification is when the page was requested from the server';`, because the page is "pre processed" on the server before being sent to the browser - but if you move that to a `.js` file, then you wont get any server side processing, so you'll get exactly that string

Comment: Unlike aspx (server-sided), JavaScript runs on the client machine. So you will need to make a new request to the external js file first, then receive the result and use it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. i need the solution without extra call